# Check if an element of array is Empty

Tags: java, arraylist, element

My method `applyBonus()` from the class `BonusEmporium` gets bonus objects from the arrayList of `City` objects and applies them to a `Player` object.
when i write my function like this i have no problem testing it:

```
public class BonusEmporium extends Bonus {
    public BonusEmporium(int cities) {
        this.setBonusType(BonusType.EMPORIUM);
        this.cities=cities;
        setCity(new ArrayList<City>(cities));
    }
    public void applyBonus(Player player){
        Bonus bonus=getCity().get(0).getBonus().get(0);//gets the first bonus from the first 
                                                       //city
        bonus.applyBonus(player);
        Bonus bonus=getCity().get(0).getBonus().get(1);//gets the second bonus from the first 
                                                       //city
        bonus.applyBonus(player);
        Bonus bonus=getCity().get(1).getBonus().get(0);//gets the first bonus from the
                                                       //second city
        bonus.applyBonus(player);
    }

}
```

The problem is when i want to run it only while the arraylists contain elements, how do i check that an element from an array is empty?

```
public class BonusEmporium extends Bonus {
    public BonusEmporium(int cities) {
        this.setBonusType(BonusType.EMPORIUM);
        this.cities=cities;
        setCity(new ArrayList<City>(cities));
    }
    public void applyBonus(Player player){
        int i=0,j=0;

            while(j<cities){
                while(getCity().get(j).getBonus().get(i)!=null){//In theory this should 
//verify that the element bonus i from the city j is not empty
//but i get NullPointerException
                    Bonus bonus=getCity().get(j).getBonus().get(i);
                    bonus.applyBonus(player);
                    i++;
                }
                j++;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: null does not mean empty

Comment: I'm close to say it does (besides null means null), maybe empty does not mean null, but its more philosophical level

Comment: @PavelNiedoba null means unassigned or not referenced. The List object itself can only have zero length if it is not null

Comment: It's clear in terms of list, marcos is asking to check for  "empty element" where null could be considered empty (like php empty() does)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what you are asking, but you should be able to avoid the error by handling the [message chain](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells/message-chains) better.

```
public void applyBonus(Player player){
    List<City> cities = getCity();
    for(int i = 0; cities != null && i < cities.size(); i++){
        City c = cities.get(i);
        List<Bonus> bonuses = c.getBonus();
        for (int j = 0; bonuses != null && j < bonuses.size(); j++) {
            Bonus b = bonuses.get(j);
            if (b != null)
                b.applyBonus(player);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: i get compilation error: The type list is not generic, it cannot be parameterized with arguments <city>

Comment: it's ok now, i had imported awt instead of util, thank you very much

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I would have used ArrayList, but that was more typing :)

Answer (score 1):

You check if the element is empty like this:

```
if(array != null && array.get(index) == null) // element is null when empty
```

To check if the array as a whole is empty (has no elements):

```
if(array != null && array.isEmpty())
```

Comment: but i want to check that it's NOT empty, that's why i wrote !=null

Comment: @marcosguerra you may invert the check of course if you want to check it's not empty

Comment: @marcosguerra note that if the `array == null` this means it's not instantiated .. empty or not empty implies that it is already instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

In general the problem in java is chaining getters like this:

```
getCity().get(j).getBonus().get(i)!=null
```

You can get nullpointer exception from 4 places here. You can check them all like:

```
if (getCity()!=null &&
   getCity().get(j) &&
   getCity().get(j).getBonus() &&
   getCity().get(j).getBonus().get(i)!=null){
....
}
```

Other way could be encapsulating whole code in try - catch and catching NPE, which is more like hack.

I also suggest using foreach instead while and don't store array size in separate variables, because you can always get it using

```
myArr.getSize()
```

And also check javadoc about ArrayList constructor:

```
new ArrayList<City>(cities)
```

because this is likely not doing what you expect

Short story:

init all ArrayLists in constructor (don't specify size)

use foreach loops

don't put nulls into the arrays

and you should be fine without checking for empty elements

Comment: i need to specify the size of that array, because the `int cities` tells you how many cities the bonus lets you choose to get their bonuses, if i leave it empty the player could choose all the cities he wants.

Comment: @marcosguerra Giving the size as a parameter **only** pre-initializes an array of that size, it does **not** prevent adding more than that number of elements